# Image Swap using CSS only and having link on image once swapped

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to swap on an image when clicked using **CSS only**. When the image is clicked and the swap has been made there should be a link to a new url when the new image is clicked, not swapped back as is the current functionality.

I had a look at this jsfiddle and it seems to accomplish much of what I want. I just have to swap the current background for background images and add a link that goes to a new url:

http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/

html

```
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label 
    for="thing"></label>
```

css

```
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label
{
background: #999;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
background: #0080FF;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Is there a way to have a link on the swapped image so it goes to a new url once the image has been swapped.

Thanks and I'd be grateful of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the `input[type=checkbox]:checked` selector. Use background-image to switch the image in the label:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}
 
input[type=checkbox] + label
{
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
height:220px;
width:220px;
background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/220/220/any);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/220/220);
}
.replacement{
  display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ a.original{
   display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ a.replacement{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> 
<br>
<a class="replacement" href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
<a class="original" href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: thanks for that, is is possible to have the swap when clicked on the actual image rather than the small box above - i'd prefer to have the swap when image is clicked and have the small box that's above the image hidden, thanks again

Comment: @new_coder See my edits. Use `background-image` on the label.

Comment: great @symlink . can the link go direct on the image and not be visible below. So when the image is swapped for example when the new image goes to the google link when clicked again, thanks for your help

Comment: @new_coder CSS doesn't have pseudo-elements for double-clicks, so that would require jQuery or Javascript. It's easy enough to do, however.

Comment: ok thanks @symlink - i was seeing if there was a way of doing it through CSS only     - thanks for your feedback